# Change bootstrap icon by using onclick function

Tags: javascript, css

I want to change the bootstrap icon `bi bi-caret-right-fill` to `bi bi-caret-down-fill`.

```
<i onclick="myFunction(this)" class="bi bi-caret-right-fill"></i>
```

```
function myFunction(x) {
   x.classList.toggle("bi bi-arrow-down-circle");
}
```

Comment: The `toggle` method removes a class, if it is already set. You don't want to remove the `bi` class, so that does not belong in there at all. You want to toggle `bi-caret-right-fill` (that is already set, and needs to be removed), and `bi-arrow-down-circle` (that is not set yet, so it needs to be added.)

Comment: So it would be: `x.classList.toggle("bi-caret-right-fill"); x.classList.toggle("bi-arrow-down-circle");` to not rely on the order in the fa css.

Comment: Note that `classList.toggle` doesn't allow multiple classes, you have to (tediously) do them one-by-one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case you need to do like this

Hope this will help you

```js
function myFunction(x) {
   x.classList.toggle("bi-caret-right-fill"); 
   x.classList.toggle("bi-arrow-down-circle"); 
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.3.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<i onclick="myFunction(this)" class="bi bi-caret-right-fill"></i>
```

Comment: `.classList.toggle("singleClass")` works [just fine](https://jsfiddle.net/vk5csuab/) you don't *have* to use add/remove.

Comment: Yeah correct @freedomn-m You can post the answer if you want.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<i onclick="myFunction(this)" class="bi bi-caret-right-fill"></i>
```

```
function myFunction(x) {
  if (x.classList.contains("bi-caret-right-fill")) {
    x.classList.remove("bi-caret-right-fill");
    x.classList.add("bi-arrow-down-circle");
  } else if (x.classList.contains("bi-arrow-down-circle")) {
    x.classList.add("bi-caret-right-fill");
    x.classList.remove("bi-arrow-down-circle");
  }
}
```